# Mostly query, few updates in nosql databases

Tags: database, nosql

In the nosql databases there is a Distinguishing Characteristic called
**Mostly query, few updates**. Can someone explain how actually this happens and compare it with relational databases.

Answer (score 0):

In my view, this is about a system which is queried a lot but updated a few.

This could be an analytical processing system that contains huge amount of data. A user of this system launches queries over this data in order to obtain some business analytics. In the heart of this system you can have either SQL or NoSQL database. The one that is more suitable for your workload.